# how to extract characters of a language

Tags: character, culture, mapping

I need to find all character in languages.
first I try to find a table that map language to a unicode range. but I can't find any thing useful. 
next I think is it possible to change language or culture and by simulation press or keydown event find characters? 
is it possible? if it is how and how I can engage shift key?

Comment: Tough to tell what you are asking.  Can you post some code?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters ?

Comment: thanks  TessellatingHeckler but I see it before and it did not cover all languages:(